# WPF: How to style or disable the default ContextMenu of a TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

Apparantly when users right-click in our WPF application, and they use the Windows Classic theme, the default ContextMenu of the TextBox (which contains Copy, Cut and Paste) has a black background.

I know this works well:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <TextBox ContextMenu="{x:Null}"/>

</Page>
```

But this doesn't work:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Page.Resources>

 <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>
</Page.Resources>

  <TextBox/>
</Page>
```

Does anyone know how to style or disable the default ContextMenu for all TextBoxes in WPF?

Comment: don't you need considering disable shortcut keys, e.g. CTRL-V?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to a late bug report we discovered that we cannot use the ApplicationComands Cut Paste and Copy directly in a partial trusted application. Therefor, using these commands in any Commmand of your controls will do absolutely nothing when executed.

So in essence Brads answer was almost there, it sure looked the right way i.e. no black background, but did not fix the problem.

We decided to "remove" the menu based on Brads answer, like so:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="TextBoxContextMenu" Width="0" Height="0" />
```

And use this empty context menu like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxContextMenu}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: or you could use <ContextMenu x:Key="key" Visibility="Collapsed" />, which also works.

Comment: Additionally, setting `IsEnabled` on ContextMenu to `false` avoids issue of the focus "freezing" when user attempts to right click.

Answer (score 32):

To style ContextMenu's for all TextBoxes, I would do something like the following:

First, in the resources section, add a ContextMenu which you plan to use as your standard ContextMenu in a textbox.
 e.g.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="TextBoxContextMenu" Background="White">
  <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
  <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
  <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Secondly, create a style for your TextBoxes, which uses the context menu resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxContextMenu}" />
</Style>
```

Finally, use your text box as normal:

```
<TextBox />
```

If instead you want to apply this context menu to only some of your textboxes, do not create the style above, and add the following to your TextBox markup:

```
<TextBox ContextMenu="{StaticResource TextBoxContextMenu}" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am sorry to stumble upon a bug.. I never realized it, but I cannot use the ApplicationCommands Cut, Copy and Paste directly in partial trust.. This menu will not work under partial trust. Clicking the menu item, does absolutely nothing.. I am sorry it took almost 18 months to discover ;)

Comment: Your answer has lead me to my new solution: disabling the menu with an empty menu.. Thanks again though for your answer!

Answer (score 22):

Bizarre. `ContextMenu="{x:Null}"` doesn't do the trick.

This does, however:

```
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Visibility="Collapsed">
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter, if you do not provide a key, it will use the `TargetType` as key just the same way my example uses :)

Taken from MSDN on Style:

> Setting the `TargetType` property to the `TextBlock` type without
>   setting an `x:Key` implicitly sets the `x:Key` to `{x:Type TextBlock}`. This also means that if you > > give the above Style an `x:Key` value of anything other than `{x:Type TextBlock}`, the Style
>   would not be applied to all TextBlock elements automatically. Instead,
>   you need to apply the style to the `TextBlock` elements explicitly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is way is what I always use:

```
      <TextBox x:Name="MyTextbox">
         <TextBox.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu Visibility="Hidden"/>
         </TextBox.ContextMenu>
      </TextBox>
```

And also can use:

```cs
           MyTextbox.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
           MyTextbox.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visble;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Comment: @Cœur that's really cool. I hadn't seen that before but will definitely use it in future. Is there a doc page for such useful features?

Comment: Take a look now, more useful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the x:Key attribute from the Style resource, leaving TargetType.  I know, you're supposed to have that x:Key for a resource, but if you have it along with your TargetType the Key prevails.

Here's a sample style that I use in a project to skin all tooltips in one of my apps (this is in App.Resources--notice, no Key)

```
 <Style
    TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter
      Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate
          TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
          <Grid
            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
            <Rectangle
              RadiusX="9"
              RadiusY="9"
              Stroke="LightGray"
              StrokeThickness="2">
              <Rectangle.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                  <GradientStop />
                  <GradientStop
                    Color="FloralWhite"
                    Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop
                    Color="Cornsilk"
                    Offset="2" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
              </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentPresenter
              Margin="6 4 6 4" />
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```