# Make TextBox Text Display Like PasswordBox Text

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to make a TextBox's Text display like a PasswordBox's Text. Is there any way by which I can do it? I think styling the TextBox may work. I tried to style it using PasswordBox's default style (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334412.aspx) but it didn't work.

Comment: It is done with code, not xaml.  Why don't you use PasswordBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `IValueConverter` in wich you replace each character in the `Text` variable of your TextBox with a `*`, then put the resulting string of stars in the tag property of your TextBox.
This way, your textbox is not showing the actual string edited (which is a password here if i understood you right).

In your binding, put `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` to get it updated on every key instead of on LostFocus. Then bind the text displayed to the `TextBox.Tag` property.

Comment: I can't spare the time right now anymore, but to point you in the right direction i updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PasswordBox in WPF since .Net 3.0 onwards.

http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Is there any reasons why you dont want to use the PasswordBox? Is there something it is not allowing you to do?

Comment: Just because I want to use bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by adding `FontFamily` of the `TextBox` as following:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YOUR_PROPERTY}"
         FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/PassDot.ttf#PassDot"
         FontSize="35"/>
```

In my case this worked just fine.

Comment: link on where to download the PassDot.ttf @Tasnim Fabiha

Comment: @Hacki https://github.com/davidagraf/passwd/blob/master/public/ttf/password.ttf you can download this from here. Back then I downloaded it from some git link like this, and that worked. I'm sure this will also work.

Comment: the "space" is not turned into a password character - • though ;(

Comment: Hi @Hacki , if the downloaded font is not working for you, can you check this answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677658/3939811