# How to set mode Password for TextBox control wpf without passwordbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to USE hidden inserted symbols in my textbox and show "password" like "*******".

But after this I will use inserted password for login. I can not use PasswordBox because it don't have need touch event.

How do I do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a TextBox be a "password box" and display stars when using MVVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119605/how-can-i-make-a-textbox-be-a-password-box-and-display-stars-when-using-mvvm)

Comment: What do you mean by _It dont have need touch event_

Comment: When i press on my passwordbox i do not see virtual keyboard, but when i tab on textbox then i see virtual keyboard. It is my problem!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please edit your post and show us what you have tried.  It is much easier for others to alter your code than to write new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/481097/4192732

You basically need a third-party extension to avoid using the passwordbox, as there are no first-party methods of masking a WPF textbox.