# Right clicking on form opens the System Menu (Close, Minimize, etc.)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window with `WindowStyle="None"` and `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"` and when I rightclick somewhere on the form, I get this showing up (I forgot what the control itself is called..)

[image]

The control which asks me if I want to Move, Size, Minimize, Maximize or close the window.. I'm wondering how I can get rid of this.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you left handed by any chance ?

Comment: We don't care that much about a screenshot of the program. Include the XAML for the window and any initialization code you do in the codebehind. EDIT: Also what is the reason you are setting `WindowStyle="None"`?

Comment: @eranotzap No. Why do you ask?

Comment: it's called a contextmenu . and when right clicking any control which has one it shows it

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Cause I've made my own, as you can see on the screenshot. (close, maximize and minimize-buttons)

Comment: are you attempting to resize with click dragging the right mouse button ?

Comment: @eranotzap no. I am not. It doesn't matter where on the form I click, that contextmenu is opening everywhere I rightclick.

Comment: yes i just realized it's the default context menu on any window

Comment: do something like this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632/wpf-how-to-style-or-disable-the-default-contextmenu-of-a-textbox 

on your window

Comment: The problem is in your code somewhere, we can't help you find it unless you show us what you did. Can you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that re-creates the behavior and provide the code in the question, as-is your question will likely be closed because there is no "one solution" to fix this and we need to see what you did to be able to tell you what you are doing that is  causeing the menu to show up.