# Change style for the default context menu in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have an WPF desktop application and many text boxes that automatically have the default context menu with `Copy\Cut\Paste` commands.

Is there any way to change style of this menu, for example add icons or change Foreground color?

https://ibb.co/y5LRZnY

Comment: You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632/wpf-how-to-style-or-disable-the-default-contextmenu-of-a-textbox)

Comment: @Alp Thank You. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `TextBox` style with a custom `ContextMenu`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu Foreground="Red">
                <MenuItem Icon="..." Command="Cut"/>
                <MenuItem Icon="..." Command="Copy"/>
                <MenuItem Icon="..." Command="Paste"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is how you would set the `Icon` property of a `MenuItem` to an image:

```
<MenuItem Command="Paste">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="pic.png" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```